# Can we get the input field value from AMP iFrame in AMP Page

Tags: amp-html

The AMP iFrame contains Jquery UI Calendar which we want to use to get the date selected by the user in our AMP Page.

Is it possible to get and pass the value in AMP iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-iframe/amp-iframe.md), `amp-iframe` does not provide any mechanism to pass configuration to the `iframe`. If you are iframing a document that was not specifically created with sandboxing in mind, you will most likely need to add `allow-scripts allow-same-origin` to the `sandbox` attribute and you might need to allow additional capabilities.